# Spring AutoWire gives Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, autowired

I have a maven mutli module project :

- Project

  -ProjectDAO

  -Projectx

ProjectDAO uses `spring + hibernate` 
From Projectx I am trying to use something like below:

```
public class TesMessage implements ITesMessage {

@Autowired
private IGlobal iGlobal;
    ...
    iGlobal.getSomeMethod();
 }
```

.. With the above code I get Null Pointer exception, Am i missing anything?

I have this in my appContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.nty.dal">
  <context:include-filter type="annotation"
    expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your application context

Comment: May you put `TesMessage` class in `com.test.nty.dal` package and add `@Repository` annotation to it?

Comment: Those two classes are in different modules of my application. will the proposed design doesn't work in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Believe the exception: Yes, you're missing something.

You don't show how you've annotated the `IGlobal` interface.  The exception suggests that it's not under Spring's control.  You have to let the Spring app context handle its creation as well as your `TextMessage`.

I would question this design.  I don't see why every text message would need something global.  Looks like a singleton bottleneck to me.

Comment: `TextMessage` is loaded only once in my application so had few things to do with. Kindly explain if something can be done better :)

Comment: My `IGlobal` is annotated with `@Repository`

Comment: I don't understand why every TextMessage needs to know about a repository.  Bad design - a circular dependency waiting to happen, since the repository will need to know about TextMessage in order to persist them.  I'd rethink it.